# How to make Aysnc annotation work in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a simple spring boot application with scheduled (`@Scheduled`) task. In that scheduled task, I would like to call async function with `@Async`, but I can see it still runs on the scheduling thread without switch to another thread. I also tried to customise executor, but no luck.  Here are some codes. 
I also already enable async in main class

```java
    public class scheduledService {
    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${config.scheduleInterval}")
    public void pollDataWithFixSchedule() {
        AsyncService service = new AsyncService();
        service.asyncCall();
        service.asyncCall();
        service.asyncCall();
 asyncCall();
    }
}
    public class AsyncService {
    @Async()
    public void asyncCall(){
       System.out.printly("Current thread -- {}",Thread.currentThread().getName()))
       Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

```java
    @Bean(name = "MyThreadPoolExecutor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(7);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(42);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(11);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyThreadPoolExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class ScheduledApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(ScheduledApplication.class);
        application.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Async` is implemented using AOP. By default that is proxy based, with proxy based AOP internal method calls aren't intercepted. No interception, no async. Either do a self injection and call the method that way, put `@Async` on the `@Scheduled` method or put the `asyncCall` method in another class (or the `@Scheduled` either will work).

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum , thanks for your answer. I create a new class including public function with Async annotation, then I new the instance in that scheduled function and call multiple times, but it doesn’t work neither. Your solution adding async to schedule function, that works but that’s not expected. Could you please advise whether I missing something

Comment: I update my code above. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Ofcourse that won't work. You are creating an instance yourself, whereas Spring should be controlling the bean and you should inject it into the class.

Answer (score 1):

according to [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async):

> @Async has two limitations:
>
> - it must be applied to public methods only
> - self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – won't work
>
> The reasons are simple – the method needs to be public so that it can be proxied. And self-invocation doesn't work because it bypasses the proxy and calls the underlying method directly.
>   so you can put your async method in a service and use it from there

Comment: This is the correct answer! You cannot call async methods from within the same class because proxying won't work

Comment: Hi @QBrute, I update my code as per suggestion, but it doesn't work neither. Could you please check my update and help point out the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to autowire **AsyncService**, do not create new object like

**AsyncService service = new AsyncService();**

Also, annotate your **scheduledService** class with @Service or @Component

```
@Service
public class scheduledService {
    @Autowired
    private AsyncService service ;

    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${config.scheduleInterval}")
    public void pollDataWithFixSchedule() {
        service.asyncCall();
        service.asyncCall();
        service.asyncCall();

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

不要在同一个类中调用异步方法
Do not call asynchronous methods in the same class.
将异步任务单独放到一个类 并且在这个类上加上@Component
Put asynchronous tasks into a single class and add @ component to this class

Answer (score -1):

Use `@EnableAsync` on the top of class where you are creating async bean, not on the ScheduledApplication.